# Google Appscript Listing elements of array with bullets and capitization

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like some help on how to list the element of an array with emails as elements (and a dynamic length) while extracting the surnames. I'm not really sure of the proper code but I have a general idea on how to do it. Here is the sample code:

```
var arrayEmail = [john.doe@gmail.com, jane.clark@gmail.com];
var regTest =new RegExp(/\.(\w+)@/);
var newArray = arrayEmail.map(function(e) {'• ' + regTest.exec(value)});
var namesList = newArray.join('\n');

Logger.log(namesList);
```

I know the code does not include the capitalization since I'm not yet familiar with that. My intended result will be a text variable and will look like.

```
• Doe
• Clark
```

Or a list with numbered items (though I am also unfamiliar with how to append increasing numbers with arrays with dynamic sizes).

```
1. Doe
2. Clark
```

Comment: Will the email always contain a `.` to separate the first name and last name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function moot() {
  const array = ['john.doe@gmail.com', 'jane.clark@gmail.com'];
  const lastnames = array
    .map(email =>
      String(email)
        .replace(/^\w+\./, '')
        .replace(/@.+$/, ''))
    .filter(String);
  const result = lastnames
    .map(name => name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1))
    .map((name, index) => (index + 1) + '. ' + name)
    .join('\n');
  console.log(result);
}
```

It is unclear why you would need to do this in Apps Script when it would probably be much easier with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula using `regexreplace()` and `proper()`.

Comment: Why is ^\w used to capture the first name in the email? When I tested the code, removing the ^ symbol in the code replace(/^\w+\./, '') yielded the same results. 

Also the variable "email" and "name" I believe denotes the element of the array? Is not necessary to declare variables when using in-line functions?

Comment: Also, since I am unable to edit the comment, why is String used in the filter(String). Doesn't the filter() method accept elements or function as an argument?

Comment: The `^` signifies the start of the text string. It is used here to guard against text strings that do not start with letter or digit, i.e., non-email addresses. `email` and `name` denote the element parameter of the two inline functions and they require no declarations. The `filter(String)` pattern weeds out zero-length text strings.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```js
function listNames () {
const arrayEmail = ["john.doe@gmail.com", "jane.clark@gmail.com"];
const namesList = arrayEmail.map( e  => "• " + toTitleCase(e.split("@")[0].split(".")[1])).join("\n");
Logger.log(namesList);
}

function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello. May ask what it is the g for in the regex pattern /\w\S*/g. Is it for the g in gmail? I thought the RegExp patterns in Google App script were denoted with / (as in /RegExp/) so in my understanding, it is outside of the regular expression.

Comment: The 'g' modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).